# Unable to sign in using Firebase phone auth

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am unable to sign in to firebase using phone auth (demo phone numbers work).

The error occurs when asking for an sms code (which never arrives) for a phone number.

```
val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(Firebase.auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(activity)
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)
            .build()
PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
```

```
[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Internal error encountered.
Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +45********, error - An internal error has occurred. [ Internal error encountered. ]
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Internal error encountered. ]
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzaaj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.3.0:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzabe.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.3.0:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzabf.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.3.0:3)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

- I have added SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys for debug, keystore, and Google play signing to the Firebase Console.
- I have updated to the newest version BoM 31.5.0 (have also tried 30.4.1 and 31.4.0 with similar results).
- I have Removed and readded the google-services.json file.
- I have checked my API key isn't restricted in the Google play console, and play services is enabled.
- I have tested through version uploaded to Google play and local build with the same result.
- I have added my debug App check token inside the Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

try to enabled device check API in console, that works for me !

Comment: Is it the Google Play Integrity API inside the Google cloud console or App Check you are referring to?

Comment: it's actually Google Play Integrity API